# Changing qmail's failure notice message

Tags: email

I want to edit the message that gets sent by qmail via the postmaster account everytime a mail can't be delivered.

Here's the original message:

```
Hi. This is the qmail-send program at xxxx.com.
I'm afraid I wasn't able to deliver your message to the following addresses.
This is a permanent error; I've given up. Sorry it didn't work out.

<xxx@xxxx.com>:
Sorry, I couldn't find any host named xxxx.com. (#5.1.2)

--- Below this line is a copy of the message.
```

The reason for doing this is because my clients are portuguese so there is no point in sending them this message in english. And I would also like to re-phrase it a bit.

I can't seem to find anything about it on the configurations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With stock qmail, it is only possible to change that message in the source code.

Comment: Thats what I was afraid of. I can't afford to recompile qmail on a production server, I guess I'll leave that for when I setup a new one. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Note that there is a [patch](http://qmail.org/qmail-bouncecontrol-1.03.patch) to qmail that allows to place the bounce message in a file. Adding that patch still requires recompiling, though. :-(

Comment: You can compile qmail on your dev box and only replace `qmail-send` in production.